# Pass columnNames dynamically to cassandraTable().select()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm reading query off of a file at run-time and executing it on the SPark+Cassandra environment.

I'm executing  :
`sparkContext.cassandraTable.("keyspaceName", "colFamilyName").select("col1", "col2", "col3").where("some condition = true")`

Query in FIle :

> select col1, col2, col3 
>   from keyspaceName.colFamilyName
>    where somecondition = true

Here Col1,col2,col3 can vary depending on the query parsed from the file.

Question :
How do I pick columnName from query and pass them to select() and runtime.

I have tried many ways to do it :
1. dumbest thing done (which obviously threw an error) -

```
var str = "col1,col2,col3"
var selectStmt = str.split("\\,").map { x => "\"" + x.trim() + "\"" }.mkString(",")
var queryRDD = sc.cassandraTable().select(selectStmt)
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Side Notes :
1. I do not want to use cassandraCntext becasue it will be depricated/ removed in next realase  (https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkCCcontext.html)
2. I'm on
    - a. Scala 2.11
    - b. spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:1.6.0-M1
    - c. Spark 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use Cassandra Connector

Your use case sounds like you actually want to use `CassandraConnector` Objects. These give you a direct access to a per ExecutorJVM session pool and are ideal for just executing random queries. This will end up being much more efficient than creating an RDD for each query.

This would look something like

```
rddOfStatements.mapPartitions( it => 
  CassandraConnector.withSessionDo { session => 
    it.map(statement => 
      session.execute(statement))})
```

But you most likely would want to use `executeAsync` and handle the futures separately for better performance.

#### Programatically specifying columns in cassandraTable

The `select` method takes `ColumnRef*` which means you need to pass in some number of `ColumnRef`s. Normally there is an implicit conversion from `String` --> `ColumnRef` which is why you can pass in just a var-args of strings.

Here it's a little more complicated because we want to pass var args of another type so we end up with double implicits and Scala doesn't like that.

So instead we pass in `ColumnName` objects as varargs (:_*)

```
========================================
 Keyspace: test
========================================
 Table: dummy
----------------------------------------
 - id                      : java.util.UUID                                                                   (partition key column)
 - txt                     : String


val columns = Seq("id", "txt")
columns: Seq[String] = List(id, txt)

//Convert the strings to ColumnNames (a subclass of ColumnRef) and treat as var args
sc.cassandraTable("test","dummy")
  .select(columns.map(ColumnName(_)):_*)
  .collect      

Array(CassandraRow{id: 74f25101-75a0-48cd-87d6-64cb381c8693, txt: hello world})

//Only use the first column
sc.cassandraTable("test","dummy")
  .select(columns.map(ColumnName(_)).take(1):_*)
  .collect

Array(CassandraRow{id: 74f25101-75a0-48cd-87d6-64cb381c8693})

//Only use the last column        
sc.cassandraTable("test","dummy")
  .select(columns.map(ColumnName(_)).takeRight(1):_*)
  .collect

Array(CassandraRow{txt: hello world})
```

Comment: Whoa !! that's a neat way of doing it... Thank you @RussS for the detailed expaination. `columns.map(ColumnName(_)):_*` worked like charm..

Comment: You saved my day :)