# Construct ColumnRef type parameter for select with Array[String] in Spark cassandra connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, select, cassandra

I read data from cassandra in a scala spark program with `com.datastax.spark.connector` like the follows:

```
val data = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "tablename").select("columnA", "columnB", ...)
```

The column names are defined in a `Array[String]` as:

```
val columnArray: Array[String] = Array("columnA", "columnB", ...)
```

There are too many columns in `columnArray` that I need to construct a parameter for select function with `columnArray`.

How to construct a `ColumnRef` type parameter for select with `Array[String]`?

Comment: I have tried the method you mentioned in the link as "select(columnArray.head, columnArray.tail: _*)",  it shows "Type mismatch, expected: ColumnRef, Actual: ColumnName".

Comment: Try this one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778104/pass-columnnames-dynamically-to-cassandratable-select. Basically, try using `.select(columnArray.map(ColumnName(_)):_*)`.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot.